# Keras loading color images

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I have 3 folders with color images. Name of the folder is label for the images inside.

```
cls1
  |____img_0.png
  |____ ...
  |____img_n.png
cls2
  |____img_0.png
  |____ ...
  |____img_n.png   
cls3
  |____img_0.png
  |____ ...
  |____img_n.png
```

I would like to use Keras library to create Convolutional neural network for classification, but I can't find, how to create dataset from color images.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please consider this [gist of pre-trained VGG-16 model with example usage](https://gist.github.com/baraldilorenzo/07d7802847aaad0a35d3) which I find illustrative:

To summarize:

1. Load your images with OpenCV or scikit-image, etc. (L58)
2. Resize and/or crop your images to fit the input size (224*224 for VGG-16)(L58)
3. Calculate and subtract for each image the mean value (L59~L61)
4. Swap the color dimension before height and width dimensions (L62)
5. If you use scikit-image, you need to swap the 3 color channels because OpenCV load images as **BGR** channels but scikit-image load it as **RGB** channels.
6. Add the batch size dimension (L63)
7. Shuffle, partition and concatenate them (along dimension 0) to form the training data `X_train`, test data `X_test` etc. along with ground truth `Y_train`, `Y_test` etc.
8. If your data-set is too big to fit in the memory, use a generator and the function `fit_generator` to do the training instead. (Keras also has `evaluate_generator` and `predict_generator`)
9. You are now ready for training.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for this kind of short overview. good answer.

Comment: The third step will remove the color dissimilarity of your images. This works in the example presented because it tries to classify a cat, which will continue to be a cat regardless of color changes in the image. If you think this information is important to you (e.g. decide between day/night; indoors/outside; classify a painting by its author), then you should probably keep it. "Global" standardization might be the solution in this case (i.e., `(image - dataset_mean)/dataset_std`).