# How to use 3 channel (RGB) images in Keras Neural-Net Model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras

I have built keras NN models with black and white images but am running into issues now that I want to use a 3 channel dataset.

`pix_vals.shape`     #pix_vals is a np.array of the RGB values for each pixel,
returns
`(261,90000,3)`       # Currently only loaded 261 images that are 300 x 300 pixels, with RGB channels

`pix_vals[0]`          #returns

```
array([[117, 110, 102],
       [118, 108, 100],
       [122, 112, 100],
       ...,
       [185, 178, 166],
       [195, 188, 178],
       [199, 191, 181]])
```

Keras will not accept this array as an input. I tried to use .reshape() to 'flatten' the array but that didn't work. Do I need to use .reshape() to create three 1D lists or arrays? (one for each color channel) What is the standard method?

I believe the below question may be on a similar question but still wasn't clear for me.
[Keras loading color images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37088571/keras-loading-color-images)

Thanks

EDIT:
The dense NN I started trying to build is as below.

```
    #dense neural network
model = keras.Sequential([
                          layers.Dense(100, activation = 'relu'),
                          layers.Dense(50, activation= 'relu'),
                          layers.Dense(50, activation= 'relu'),
                          layers.Dense(1, activation = 'softmax')
])

#2. Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model_history = model.fit(train_images,
                          train_labels,
                          epochs=10,
                          batch_size=100)
```

This returned the value error:
ValueError: Shapes (None,) and (None, 300, 300, 1) are incompatible

Should I be reshaping the data, using similar code to below:

```
train_images = train_images.reshape((int(num_images*0.8), 300, 300, 3))
```

Comment: Consider using layers like `Conv2D` having `input_size` like `(img_h, img_w, 3)`

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide some code snippet regarding where you are getting an error and the exact error message. It is most likely an issue with either the shape of the data or the shape of the input.